# Is there much better way to write this Java method?

Tags: java, arrays, list, bufferedreader

This is supposed to list every word from a user defined text file and then put them into an array.  This is my first attempt at java in a long time and I just know this is a mess.

```
public static String[] parse(String path) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    try <BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Trying to make sure I make words between the spaces and punctuation

            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                int x;
                if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))) {
                    x = i;}
                    for (int a = x; a < line.length(); a++) {
                        if (!Character.isLetter(line.charAt(a))) {
                            String s = line.substring(x, a)
                            list.add(s);
                            i = a;
                            a = line.length() + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        return arr;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should ask in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Certainly: start by breaking down the function in smaller functions. Reduce the indentation (it's just too much). Don't use arrays, use lists. After that you'll get much more readable code.

Comment: edit: line.charAt(x, a) changed to line.substring(x, a) for what it's worth

Comment: There is certainly a better way to *indent* it. The current formatting makes no sense.

Comment: flagged to close, since the question isn't about a problem. better to ask in code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is much more appropriate and faster in this case:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path))) {
    //Everything that's not a character is treated as delimiter
    sc.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        words.add(sc.next());
    }
}
```

And for Java 9 it's even simpler:

```
final List<String> words;
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path))) {
    sc.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");
    words = sc.tokens().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to get all the words from a file and put it into a list, you can do it in a much simpler way as below:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
     // Now you have a String array containing each word in the current line
     //Add all words to list as below.
     list.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));
   }
```

your list would now have all the words.
To convert the list to string[]..

```
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
return arr;
```

Comment: this would be great, is there a way to include every possible punctuation as a split point too?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to split on one or more white-space characters (after trimming the line), and then use a regular expression to remove everything not a letter (instead of a character by character test). And you can use an empty array in `List.toArray` it will size it for you. And never silently swallow exceptions. Something like,

```
public static String[] parse(String path) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            for (String token : tokens) {
                token = token.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
                if (!token.isEmpty()) {
                    list.add(token);
                }
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: if a line said "this!@is a sentence.......", "this," "is," "a," and "sentence" should all be stored.